# How can I left align an image on the header part of the page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[Left align image?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgR6T.png)

Hey everyone I'm working on a WordPress site and have ran into a slight problem. I've gotten to add the right image onto the header (more specifically the ads section of Newspaper panel) but when I try to add another image it gets placed on top of the other one when I want it to posted to the left of it.

```
<a href="https://www.villaisisstlucia.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
<img id= villa class= "right" src= 
"https://www.caribbeannewsglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/villaIS_728.gif" width="370" height="450" />
</a>

<a href="https://www.villaisisstlucia.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
<img id= villa class= "left" src= 
"https://www.caribbeannewsglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Top-Header-Banner.gif" width="370" height="450" />
</a>
```

This is generally the code I've used to try to fix it and I thought switching class="right" to class="left" would help but it never worked and I'm not sure what to do.

Any help would be appreciated